# Local sudden error: Class 'NunoMaduro\Collision\Adapters\Laravel\CollisionServiceProvider' not found

Tags: laravel, composer-php

I have a laravel app, and locally it was working fine last week. When I tried to run it now, it gives me this error:

```
[2022-07-27 23:35:57] local.ERROR: Class 'NunoMaduro\Collision\Adapters\Laravel\CollisionServiceProvider' not found {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalThrowableError(code: 0): Class 'NunoMaduro\\Collision\\Adapters\\Laravel\\CollisionServiceProvider' not found at /home/vagrant/Desktop/.../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/ProviderRepository.php:208)
[stacktrace]
```

I saw lots of solutions for production issues, and to update the composer, but mine was working fine for the last 6 months.

Answer (score 0):

Inside of your `composer.lock`.

Move `"nunomaduro/collision"` from `"require-dev"` to `"require"`.

Then run `composer install`.

Comment: Why does it have to be changed suddenly? I am in my dev environment, production works fine